# /users/{ids}/timeline creation_date missing or incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.1, timeline

I am writing a small widget that displays the time since I was awarded my last badge on Stack Overflow. I noticed that my most recent badge was missing from the timeline data (/users/{ids}/timeline).

After a bit more investigation, I found there are several badges that do not have a `creation_date` field, and these badges appear at the end of the returned data.

For example, when I run this query:
[/2.1/users/1367622/timeline?fromdate=1375920000&todate=1376006400&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1367622/timeline?fromdate=1375920000&todate=1376006400&site=stackoverflow)

I get:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "timeline_type": "badge",
      "user_id": 1367622,
      "badge_id": 83,
      "detail": "Fanatic"
    }
  ],
  "quota_remaining": 9951,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": false
}
```

This is the correct date I was awarded the badge, however the `creation_date` field is missing. From looking at [the doco](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline), it was my understanding that the `creation_date` cannot be absent.

When I run this query to get all my timeline data:
[/2.1/users/1367622/timeline?page=3&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1367622/timeline?page=3&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow)

the last items are:

```
{
  "creation_date": 1217540781,
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 2278,
  "detail": "Custodian"
},
{
  "creation_date": 1217540573,
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 2278,
  "detail": "Custodian"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 6,
  "detail": "Supporter"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 7,
  "detail": "Critic"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 8,
  "detail": "Citizen Patrol"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 9,
  "detail": "Autobiographer"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 13,
  "detail": "Yearling"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 31,
  "detail": "Commentator"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 32,
  "detail": "Civic Duty"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 71,
  "detail": "Enthusiast"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 83,
  "detail": "Fanatic"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 1306,
  "detail": "Analytical"
},
{
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "badge_id": 2600,
  "detail": "Informed"
}
```

It appears that it is only user timeline objects with `timeline_type` "badge" that are missing the `creation_date` property, however there are items with an incorrect `creation_date` as well.

The top 2 items above do have a `creation_date`, but it is not correct. These two Custodian badges have `creation_date`s of 31/7/2008, but [my timeline on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367622/steph-sharp?tab=activity&sort=badges) says they were actually awarded on 5/6/2013. I wasn't even a member of Stack Overflow in 2008, I joined in 2012!

Another example is this badge in my timeline:

```
{
  "creation_date": 1335872416,
  "post_type": "question",
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "post_id": 10397150,
  "badge_id": 26,
  "title": "Infinite Scrolling - setContentOffset: stops deceleration of UIScrollView",
  "detail": "Popular Question"
},
```

This badge item contains all the necessary information, but the `creation_date` is the date I asked the original question, not the date I was awarded the badge.

I don't think this issue is just with badges either. For example, the same query includes this:

```
{
  "creation_date": 1254058162,
  "post_type": "question",
  "timeline_type": "revision",
  "user_id": 1367622,
  "post_id": 1483581,
  "title": "Get notified when UITableView has finished asking for data?",
  "detail": "Added code markers."
},
```

The `creation_date` returned is 27/9/2009, but the actual date for [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1483581/revisions) was 17/6/2013.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Interesting. For that edit, it is returning the time of the question's creation, many moons before your edit. (And way before you joined SO)

Comment: @BrockAdams You're right, I hadn't noticed that the edit was returning the date the original question was asked, just like the "Popular Question" badge item above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

The bug was basically selecting the wrong date to display (in this case, an associated post), and the right date for filtering and what not.  Since not all badges are associated with a post, not all displayed dates were set and when they *were* set they were off by some (basically random) amount.