# Timeline activities appear to be missing (because creation_date has wrong and useless values)

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, users, timeline

When I'm looking at [my Stack Overflow timeline according to the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users#ids=4751173&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), It's missing a lot of events.

[image]

According to the API, the last thing I did was posting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059380/4751173), five days ago, and you can see edits are reported as well (the second entry). However, I've made a couple of more edits since then, as you can see in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=all):

[image: all actions on my profile]

It can't be the case that actions via the API are not reported; I've made a couple of manual edits as well, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/873432/revisions) was a manual edit via the website itself.

Accessing the timeline via [`/me/timeline`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-timeline) doesn't make a difference; I get the same results. As for other sites: on Meta Stack Exchange, my last reported action is [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331167/why-not-show-the-appointed-elected-date-for-moderators-on-all-stack-exchange-sit#comment1080124_331167) but <s>I</s> my script made three edits since then; some other sites, like the Russian Stack Overflow and Photography, the timeline is up-to-date.

Comment: If/when this gets fixed, I recommend that "creation_date" be replaced with "event_date" for this object -- to avoid ongoing confusion and regression of this bug in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a variation of [this bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/4416/the-api-questions-ids-timeline-path-doesnt-return-several-items-that-occurre) and a variation or repeat of [this bug that was partially fixed (once upon a time)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4270/users-ids-timeline-creation-date-missing-or-incorrect).

Anyway, the **timeline *does* show all your events** as can be seen with this query:
    [/2.2/users/4751173/timeline?fromdate=1563667200&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users#fromdate=2019-07-21&ids=4751173&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
where `1563667200` is midnight on July 21st, 2019.

The problem is that `creation_date` is (still/again) all kinds of FUBAR and does not refer to the actual time of the event.

For example, the above query returns an item:

```
{
  "post_id":        2818028,
  "user_id":        4751173,
  "timeline_type": "revision",
  "post_type":      "answer",
  "creation_date":  1273661209,
  "detail":         "broken image fixed (click 'side-by-side' to see...",
  "title":          "Equivalent of Bloch&#39;s Effective Java for C#"
},
```

where creation_date is `1273661209`.
`1273661209` corresponds to `2010-05-12 10:46:49 UTC` which is the **time that the answer was created, NOT when the edit was made.** (And also well before the `fromdate`.)

This, of course, makes little sense and is not useful for the timeline.